# Google maps v.3 Javascript geolocation mobile

Tags: android, mobile, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I am a designere and I have no experience and I have this javascript code to which I would add geolocation instead of giving a fixed position

```
function initialize() {

        /* Style of the map */
        var styles = [
        {
          stylers: [
            { hue: "#00ffe6" },
            { saturation: -20 }
          ]
        },{
          featureType: "road",
          elementType: "geometry",
          stylers: [
            { lightness: 100 },
            { visibility: "simplified" }
          ]
        },{
          featureType: "road",
          elementType: "labels",
          stylers: [
            { visibility: "off" }
          ]
        },{
             featureType: "poi",
             elementType: "labels",
             stylers: [
               { visibility: "off" }
             ]
           }

         ];


      // Create a new StyledMapType object, passing it the array of styles,
      // as well as the name to be displayed on the map type control.
      var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, {name: "Styled Map"});

      /* Lat. and Lon. of the center of the map */
      var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(37.812407, 13.301522);

      // Create a map object, and include the MapTypeId to add
      // to the map type control.
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12,               //zoom level
        center: myCenter,       //center position
        scrollwheel: false,     //zoom when scroll disable
        zoomControl: true,      //show control zoom

        mapTypeControlOptions: {
          mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style'] 
        }

      };

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);

      //Associate the styled map with the MapTypeId and set it to display.
      map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
      map.setMapTypeId('map_style');



      var marker4= new google.maps.Marker({position:new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude)});

      /* Marker MyPub */
      var contentString1 = 
          '<div class="popup">'+
          '<h2> My Pub</h2>'+
          '<p>Example Strasse n.1</b><br/>'+
          '<small><b>Lat.</b> 52.520196, <b>Lon.</b> 13.406067</small></p>'+
          '<a target="_blank" href="http://www.marchettidesign.net">'+
          'Visit Web Site &#187;</a> '+
          '</div>';

      var infowindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: contentString1,
          maxWidth: 230,
          maxHeight: 300,

      });

      var myLatLng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(37.812407, 13.301522);
      var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng1,
          map: map,
          title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function() {
        infowindow1.open(map,marker1);
      });

        /* Marker Ice Cream */
      var image2 = 'img/ice-cream.png';
      var myLatLng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(52.543437, 13.352719);
      var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng2,
          map: map,
          icon: image2
      });

      /* Marker Food */
      var image3 = 'img/food.png';
      var myLatLng3 = new google.maps.LatLng(52.518439, 13.385124);
      var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng3,
          map: map,
          icon: image3
      });

       /* Hide Markers when zoom <= 12 x */
      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
        var zoom = map.getZoom();

        if (zoom <= 12) {
            marker3.setMap(null);
            marker2.setMap(null);
            marker1.setMap(null);
        } else {
            marker3.setMap(map);
            marker2.setMap(map);
            marker1.setMap(map);
        }
      });

       /* open popup marker when map is load */
      new google.maps.event.trigger( marker, 'click' );         

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

looking on the internet since cordova use as a framework for mobile versions I found this example but I can not join with the 'other to give the' desired look to my map

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){

        var mapProp = {center:new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude)};
        var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapProp);
        var marker=new google.maps.Marker({position:new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude)});
        marker.setMap(map);
        }, function(error){
            if(error.code == PositionError.PERMISSION_DENIED)
            {
                alert("App doesn't have permission to use GPS");
            }
            else if(error.code == PositionError.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE)
            {
                alert("No GPS device found");
            }
            else if(error.code == PositionError.TIMEOUT)
            {
                alert("Its taking too long find user location");
            }
            else
            {
                alert("An unknown error occured");
            }
        }, { maximumAge: 3000, timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true });
    }, false);
```

Can anyone give me an 'idea of how to merge the two codes or how to create two separate sheets of styles so that the geolocation not give me problems with the style but I locate only the' user?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the HTML5 `navigator.geolocation` to get the user's current location.

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPositionCallBack);
} else {
    alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
}

function showPositionCallBack(position) {
    youCode(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
}
```